# Hypothesis testing two weighted Poisson Binomial Distributions with different lengths

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I have two groups of people: each group is made by subgroups of people coming from census areas of which I know the probability of being male vs female.
I can calculate the distribution: is a Poisson Binomial distribution.

```
library(poibin)
group_1_quantity = c(10, 5, 20)
group_1_probabilities = c(0.55,0.57,0.60)
group_2_quantity = c(5, 8, 12, 18)
group_2_probabilities = c(0.49,0.45,0.58, 0.49)

probability_of_exactly_n_group_1 <- 1:sum(group_1_quantity)
probability_of_exactly_n_group_2 <- 1:sum(group_2_quantity)


distrib_group_1 <- dpoibin(kk = probability_of_exactly_n_group_1, 
        pp = group_1_probabilities, 
        wts = group_1_quantity)
plot(distrib_group_1)
```

[image: Probability Distribution Group 1]

```
distrib_group_2 <- dpoibin(kk = probability_of_exactly_n_group_2, 
                           pp = group_2_probabilities, 
                           wts = group_2_quantity)   
plot(distrib_group_2)
```

[image]

I have calculated the expected value by selecting the bin with the maximum value in each of the two probability distributions.I have also found the confidence interval given say alpha = 0.05, by using the cumulative distribution using **ppoibin** and computing where is the probability mass.

Now, I assume that the things I just said is correct, I wonder: how can I do a sort of Fisher Test and understand wether the two distributions, and in particular the two expected values with their confidence intervals, differ significantly with a certain confidence? Please also consider that the resulting discrete distribution have different lengths, up to the amount of people in each of the two original groups.

Comment: You say you know the varying probabilities $p_i$, so I do not understand what there is to test?

Comment: I have two discrete probability distributions, similarly-shaped, with different lengths. I would like to test if the two groups differ "significantly". I even thought about resampling or bootstrapping but I am sure I am not understanding something basic.

Comment: You will not get any answers without a much better description of your problem. Your best bet is to ask your real problem, in language of the problem, not trying to abstract it with concepts you possibly have misunderstood! Read https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I've done my best here ->
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461300/comparing-groups-of-people-coming-from-different-census-areas