# Comparing groups of people coming from different census areas

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

Group 1 has G1 people: I know precisely that it's composed by X number of people that come from the census area A1, Y number of people from area A2, Z number of people from area An.

X = 10
Y = 12
Z = 13

G1 = X + Y + Z

For each census area, I know the total population and the number of males: since I know the proportion of males, then I know the probability that if I pick a random person from A1, this person is a man.

Say: P(M | X) = 0.55, P(M | Y) = 0.51, P(M | Z) = 0.60

I have managed to find a distribution that will tell me the distribution of number of successes (how many males) I can expect in group A, and I have plotted this using the Weighted Poisson Binomial Distribution.

Here is an example with G1 = 35

[image]

I have Group 2, with cardinality G2, composed of different amounts of people coming from the same or other census areas. I can find the distribution of males as I did before; for example I have 43 people, and the distribution of males look like this.

[image]

How can I know, given these two discrete distributions, wether the two groups differ significantly with, say, 95% confidence?